# Is bloating after a six month vegan diet transition period still normal?

Tags: veganism, health, transitioning-diets

I have been vegan for about half a year now, but the bloating and gas are still a problem. I've read that the body will get used to it after a certain time, but I think it should be better by now, shouldn't it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If a lot of your meals tend to contain beans of any sort, it can cause this issue. [Reportedly](http://www.scottjurek.com/eat-run/), if you use the Mexican spice, Epazote (available on Amazon) when cooking your meal containing beans, you will see an improvement. I haven't tried it myself yet but I've bought some to test with and will update

Comment: Hello, welcome to Vegetarianism Stack Exchange :) Could you please add some source for the claim that the Epazote spice allegedly alleviates the issue? It would improve your answer so that interested users (such as me in this case) could easily read up on that in the future.Thanks :)

Comment: Sure :) Originally I read about it in Scott Jurek's book, Eat and Run (and that it was great for bloating caused by beans) so I searched on Amazon for it and the reviews all said it really helps - I don't have a evidence based article unfortunately - just people's say so :)

Comment: @FelicityRatcliffe Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 0):

Bloating on a vegetarian diet is usually caused by these factors:

1. Having lot of raw (uncooked) food
2. Eating foods high in protein at night, which doesn't allow it to get digested properly resulting in gas. (e.g. moong dal and other pulses)
3. I'm not sure about this, but some people also recommend avoiding drinking water for at least 60 mins after a meal.

Comment: Supposedly, drinking water with or before food dilutes digestive juices which causes digestion to take longer which could lead to gas. Are you sure it's protein to blame in the pulses rather than indigestible carbohydrates?